# HTTP POST request with different format of the url

Tags: android, http-post

I am developing an Android app for a Company. While working on the API the company guys gave me a login API something like this

```
"app.abc.com/Login?data={"email":"abc","pwd":"123"} "
```

I am using volley library but I don't know how to post data like this since I have not done it before.

I need advice and wanted to know if this is the right way.

Comment: That is an url with query parameters. So you should execute a GET request. Not POST.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of volley ..try to use android networking library

--to do this :add 
--compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:0.4.0'
to your gradle file.`enter code here`

```
 AndroidNetworking.post("your login URL")
                .setTag("Login")
                .addBodyParameter("email", "abc")
                .addBodyParameter("pwd", "123")
                .setPriority(Priority.IMMEDIATE)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject dataJson = response.getJSONObject("data");
                            boolean status = dataJson.getBoolean("success");

                            } else {
                                JSONArray errorJsonArray = dataJson.getJSONArray("errors");
                                String errorMsg;
                                for (int i = 0; i < errorJsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                    errorMsg = errorJsonArray.get(i).toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                                Log.e("Error", response.toString());


                            }


                        } catch (JSONException je) {
                            je.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError anError) {


                        try {
                            if (anError.getErrorBody() != null) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(anError.getErrorBody());
                                JSONObject dataJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dataJsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), anError.getErrorDetail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.e("Error", anError.getErrorDetail());
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Volley - Create the request queue

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);  // this = context
```

Then create the postRequest, should look somthing like (using Volley):

```
url = "app.abc.com/Login";
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
    new Response.Listener<String>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // response
            Log.d("Response", response);
        }
    }, 
    new Response.ErrorListener() 
    {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             // error
             Log.d("Error.Response", response);
       }
    }
) {     
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
    {  
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
            params.put("data", "{\"email\":\"abc\",\"pwd\":\"123\"}");
            return params;  
    }
};
queue.add(postRequest);
```

I also recommend using Retrofit and GSON libraries (a bit learning curve here but it is worth it since they are very powerful libraries)